# Creating a mindmap using CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, mindmapping, mindmap

I want to create a mindmap of money that I have sent and received using a CSV file with columns: from, to, money in, and money out.

[image: Exmaples from the CSV file]

I want to create a graph that shows money either moving in or out of each account, with the account I want to choose in the center.

[image: What I am envisioning]

I can't find a python library that does this. Is there a library that would let me do this? Or is that even possible using Python?

Comment: It's possible to do in python but there is no dedicated library for mind-map as far as I know. You have to cook up a way to make the graph using `matplotlib` library.

Comment: https://github.com/MartinPacker/filterCSV

Comment: you could create a graph structure and visualize it. check out https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-networks-in-python-d70f4cbeb259

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from graphviz import Digraph
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

G = Digraph(format='jpeg')

G.attr(rankdir='LR', size='8,5')
G.attr('node', shape='circle')

df = pd.read_csv('so.csv')

# add the vertices
[G.node(str(x)) for x in np.unique(df[['From', 'To']].values.flatten())]
# add the edges
[G.edge(str(x[1][0]), str(x[1][1]), label=str(x[1][2])) for x in df.iterrows()]

G.render('sg', view=True)
```

Where the content of `so.csv` is:

```
From,To,Amount
Account1,Account2,20
Account1,Account3,50
Account3,Account1,60
```

You will have:

[image]